# Key-value design in redis

Tags: redis, memcached

I just begun work with redis. I have problem when work with it. I have a list of users.

I have a page that displays a list of users, in that page I have pagination, sorting, filter by name address... How can I design key-value redis for easy use?

Comment: The question is too broad. Please be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Redis is not exactly suited for an SQL-alike usage. What I mean is that usually you get data the way you put data in Redis.

Having a list of users with pagination, if you don't need too much filtering, or just limited filtering, can be a good use case using a *sorted set* data type where you have your user IDs as values, and the unix time as *score*. If you need another listing sorted by a different field, you'll likely need an additional *sorted set*, and so forth.

As far as filtering is concerned, you may do it server-side getting ranges from the sorted set and removing the non-matching items if they are sparse. However you can see how this will not scale if your filter selects 10 elements out of millions.

So the applicability of Redis in your use case depends on the exact details, and in general it looks like you may want a database more suitable for complex queries, even if you are likely going to pay the performance price.